# How to access one controller ActionMethod with different controller's Action method using ActionLink with ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on an application which include 3 models and 3 Controllers (RawMaterial, Supplier and PurchaseOrder). Here are my Classes.

```
public class RawMaterial
{
    public int RawMAterialID { get; set; }
    public string RawMaterialName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string SupplierAddress { get; set; }


    public virtual List<RawMaterial> RawMaterials { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RawMaterial> RawMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

PO's Index View

```
<td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add RawMaterials", "POMaterialsCreate", "RawMaterial", new { id = item.PurchaseOrderID }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PurchaseOrderID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PurchaseOrderID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PurchaseOrderID })
    </td>
```

RawMaterials Controller HTTPGET CreateMethod

```
public ActionResult POMaterialsCreate(int id)
    {
        var POrawMaterials = db.RawMaterials.SingleOrDefault(s => s.PurchaseOrderID == id);

        ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName");
        return View(POrawMaterials);
    }
```

RM HTTPPOST CreateMethod

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult POMaterialsCreate(RawMaterial rawMaterial)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.RawMaterials.Add(rawMaterial);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("POMaterials");
        }


        ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName", rawMaterial.SupplierID);
        return View(rawMaterial);
```

RouteConfig File

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I am accessing supplier list on rawMaterials form in ddl.On PurchaseOrders "Create" ActionMethod I am creating new Purchase Order and then I am redirected to the PurchaseOrders "Index" ActionMethod where I can see the list of all POs.Now on POs Index view page I have added Link `@Html.ActionLink("Add RawMaterials","Create","RawMaterial",{id = item.PurchaseOrderID},null)`with each row in the list.

When the User click on this link on PurchaseOrder's "Index" page it should go to RawMaterial controller's HttpGet "POMaterialsCreate" ActionMethod with the PO's id and on the other hand  pass it as a parameter in HttpGet "POMaterialsCreate" method.

How do I handle this Id in RawMaterial HttpGet and HttpPost "POMaterialsCreate" methods so that I can create multiple RawMaterials against single PurchaseOrderID? and how do I show this PO ID in RM create View?

Answer (score 0):

I mean your link should be: @Html.ActionLink("Add RawMaterials","Create","POMaterialsCreate",{id=PurchaseOrderID},null)

have also a look at the debugger console in the browser

Comment: That is just a Text.Please check the RM's "POMaterialsCreate" Method and its {code} and tell me where I am doing wrong